# Start X after automatic login

Tags: bash, arch-linux, xorg

I have a working automatic login to a virtual console after boot.
Now I want the X server to start automatically, instead of typing `startx`.
This worked before, but after switching to systemd, X would not start itself.
According to the [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login), I edited my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

But X won´t start (executing `startx` manually works).

The wiki also notes:

> X must always be run on the same tty where the login occurred, to
>   preserve the logind session. This is handled by the default
>   /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc.

But I am not sure how to handle this.
My `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$XDG_VTNR" ]; then
  exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@"
else
  exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### UPDATE

`~/.xinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

# Keyboard layout
setxkbmap -layout de nodeadkeys
# Set the cursor
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

# Autostart
tint2 & #Taskbar
/usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon & #Notifications
numlockx & #activate numlock

case "$1" in
    openbox)
        exec ck-launch-session openbox-session ;;
    xmonad)
        exec ck-launch-session xmonad ;;
    *) #default
        exec ck-launch-session xmonad ;;
esac
```

I don´t have a `~/.Xresources` file and I didn´t need one before. Is it important?

Comment: Remove the consolekit stuff from your `.xinitrc`; systemd has replaced that functionality...

Comment: Curious why you don't use one of the X display managers and set auto-login there. KDM and GDM both have auto-login (if you're already using one of those desktop environments). Not sure about XDM. Or use nodm, which does what you want and is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what XDG_VTNR implicates, but this script works for me,
put the line to `~/.bashrc`

(I do auto-X on tty3)

`if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty3 ]]; then exec startx; fi`

Also define "not working", does it work if you launch `startx` manually? If not, examine your ~/.xinitrc first.

Comment: Executing `startx` manually works, updated question.

Comment: @user905686 check this link https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1188688

Comment: this doesn´t really help...

Comment: Ok I tried this now and it works. Any idea why the wiki instructions do not work?
Can you also explain what your command does?
The second part checks whether we are on tty3 so startx will really be executed only once, right?

Answer (score 0):

In `.bash_profile`, you can find out (after autologin with `getty -a` in `/etc/inittab`) what tty you are in with `tty` (if you're in fact in X, it could look like this: `/dev/pts/1` - this is what the `p` check is about below). Then, set a variable to store this information; later, use it to launch X with `xinit`.

You should also setup `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.Xresources`; a good start of `~/.xinitrc` is `xrdb ~/.Xresources` - check the man pages for all of this. You can find some examples [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/conf/index.php).

```
CURRENT_VT=`tty`
if [[ ${CURRENT_VT[6]} == "p" ]]; then
    export VT="X"
else
    export VT=${CURRENT_VT: -1:1}
fi

# ... [cut] initialize everything else ...

# OK, done; let's start applications and X depending on where we are

case $VT in
    (1) emacs ;;
    (5) wait_for_internet
        irssi --connect=open.ircnet.net ;;
    (6) xinit ;;
    (X) ... do X stuff ... ;;
esac
```

**EDIT**

By mistake, I posted the above zsh code - in bash syntax, it would look somewhat like this (with the reservation that it is much less tested than the zsh code, which runs every day on my computer). The rest is unchanged.

```
CURRENT_VT=`tty`
if [[ ${CURRENT_VT:5:1} = "p" ]]; then
    export VT="X";
else
    export VT=${CURRENT_VT:${#CURRENT_VT} - 1};
fi
```

Comment: @Gilles: It seems to work in `.bashrc` as well (when I changed the syntax; see the edit) - the reason I thought it would go there, is that I have it in `.zshrc` - so either those files are not 100% parallel, **or** you don't think the above belongs in `.zshrc` either - I sort of suspect the latter (as there is a `.zprofile`), so it would be interesting to know why?

Comment: If you put this code in `.bashrc`, it'll trigger in all kinds of undesirable circumstances, such as running screen, or SSH if it's forwarding the `XDG_VTNR` variable, or in an xterm if you've unset `DISPLAY`, etc.

Comment: @Gilles: Is this the case for zsh as well? (That is, you should use `.zprofile`?)

Comment: Yes, no matter what the shell is, starting X goes into the login script (`.profile`, `.login`, `.bash_profile`, `.zprofile`, …), not the interactive startup script (`.bashrc`, `.kshrc`, `.cshrc`, `.zshrc`, …).

Comment: @Emanuel Berg: I thought you should use `startx` and not `xinit`? Updated my question with other files.

Comment: @user905686: `man startx`: `The startx script is a front end to xinit(1) that provides a somewhat nicer user interface for running a single session of the X Window System.` Anyway, `xinit` always worked for me. As for `~/.xinitrc`, I use that to set some properties (e.g., disable the beep with `xset b 0`) **and** start my everyday applications (e.g., `urxvt`). Also, first thing in that file is `xrdb ~/.Xresources` - this file is used to configure the X applications: for example, the size of my terminal emulator: `URxvt.geometry: 77x28`. See the link for more examples. Keep trying :)