# How to boot Kali Linux in GUI mode

Tags: kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux MATE 2019.2 into VMware, and it boots in console mode.

**Q:** Is this the standard behavior of Kali or has something gone wrong in my setup?

I can start the GUI by typing `startx` and it works perfectly, but I'd prefer to boot directly into GUI.

**Q:** How can I reconfigure Kali Linux to start with the GUI before the logon?

This is **not a duplicate** of the various "why my distribution suddenly stopped to boot to GUI" questions:

- This is a fresh install: even at the first boot it didn't boot to GUI (apart from the graphical installer).
- I certainly don't want to just add `startx` to a user script. I want the GUI to start *before* the login, and get the graphical logon screen (i.e. the "display manager").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force "startx" at startup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401884/how-to-force-startx-at-startup)

Comment: Or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193163/i-have-to-run-startx-on-boot-to-have-a-window-manager-how-can-i-fix-this) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62722/start-x-after-automatic-login).

Comment: @Sparhawk it doesn't seem a duplicate of those questions. This is a fresh install of Kali (a Debian bases distribution) and this behavior has been present since the first boot.

Comment: The solution should be the same, i.e. put `startx` in a startup script.

Comment: No, because that would happen after the login. I want to get the graphical login screen.

Comment: Ah right. That's called the "display manager". [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux) is possibly the right dupe then?

Comment: But why it is missing in a fresh install of Kali MATE 2019.2? Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure. However, I'm not surprised… you know that Kali [is not a general purpose distro](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/18887) right? It's missing a lot of things, and has some defaults that are intentionally insufficient for everyday use (e.g. root user).

Comment: Of course but from the tutorials and  the guides this doesn't seem the default behavior of a standard Kali setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute command before user login on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not graphical mode is started upon boot is determined by the run level / default target set by `init` / `systemd`.  Also, without a graphical display manager present you will not have a login screen.  Since you have installed a Mate-based distro I assume, however, that the former is the problem.

Please check the output of the command (as root):

```
# systemctl get-default
```

If it is not

```
graphical.target
```

Then you can set the default by entering:

```
# systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Also you need to enable a display manager, or else boot will fail.  Try:

```
# systemctl enable gdm
# systemctl start gdm
```

If there were no errors reboot and let us know.

If the `systemctl enable gdm` fails you may have a different dm like `lightdm`; try this:

```
# systemctl enable lightdm
# systemctl start lightdm
```

Upon errors let us know.  Don't reboot until one of the display managers works!

Comment: If you want to test `graphical.target` as one-time only (e.g. to see if it works before fully committing to it) you can use `systemctl isolate graphical.target`. If something goes wrong, you'll only need to reboot and you'll be back in console mode. Once you see the GUI mode works correctly, then you can do `systemctl set-default graphical.target` with confidence.

Comment: @telcoM Good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Login to `tty1`

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -f gdm3
```